# Headless chrome authentication and ssl error in linux

Tags: python, linux, selenium, ssl, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access to our internal company site to pull screenshot of it using headless chrome on redhat linux.

For this I am using Python, Selenium, Poppler and Chromedriver.

It is working perfectly on Windows, however on non-gui linux without options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') its returning white blank page but with ('ignore-certificate-errors') option added its giving 401 error.
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       
handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (handlSSLErr);

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(FLASK_STATIC_FOLDER,'chromedriver'),options=options)

       
URL = '"our internal webpage/"%s' %int(facemapperid)

driver.get(URL)
```

If you have any suggestions

Comment: That error is coming from the server, not the client. That message is telling you that you need to be logged in or otherwise authenticated to access that page. So what are the authentication requirements for that page?

Comment: Hey, its using basic authentication. Is there anyway to authenticate with selenium?

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41487/how-can-i-handle-the-chrome-http-authentication-popup-window-in-selenium-without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by doing below

```
First I made connection to let it cache my cookie
driver.get("https://username:password@mywebsite")
and then do it again
URL = 'username:password@mywebsite
```

Answer (score 0):

The option to ignore certificate error is

```
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
```

You missed to add `--`